# Fetching all column names in nested json

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

I am trying to read a nested json file.

Is there any way to store all of the column names in this json file.

```
class ReadData {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Search").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc= new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
        DataFrame df1 = sqlContext.read().json("TestData.json");
        df1.printSchema();
        String columns[]=df1.columns();
        int total_columns=columns.length;
        System.out.println("column names :");
        for(int i=0;i<total_columns;i++){
            System.out.println(columns[i]);
        }
   }
```

Contents of TestData.json :

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "name": {
      "first_name":"Joe",
      "last_name":"Thomas"
    }
}
```

The output of my code:

```
column names :

id
name
```

Expected output is :

```
column names :
id
name.first_name
name.last_name
```

Comment: will be wonderful if you can provide more information on what is in the `json` file and elaborate more on you expected output. Without proper inputs it is almost impossible for the community to predict the input and output.

Comment: Thank you Samuel for the response. The json file has contents :{"id":"1","name":{"first_name":"Joe","last_name":"Thomas"}}                            I want all the column names of the json like id,name.first_name and name.last_name

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far and what is blocking you from getting what you needed? Will appreciate if you can post your code and share with us so we can fix it for you

Comment: I have tried the above code but unable to get expected output. Can you please refer the code and description and suggest some improvements in the code to get the expected output. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution to your problem. I have tried to handle some of the scenarios but this should do the trick.

```
package com.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONColumnNameExtract {

static List<String> colNames;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    colNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    String jsonString = "";
    try {
        jsonString = readFile("C:\\jsonInput.json",
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject mainJObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    Iterator<?> keys = mainJObject.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) keys.next();
        if (mainJObject.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) mainJObject.get(key);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                iterateJSON(array.get(i), key);
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (mainJObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
            iterateJSON(mainJObject.get(key), key);
        } else {
            if (!colNames.contains(key))
                colNames.add(key);
        }
    }
    for (String colName : colNames)
        System.out.println(colName);
}

private static void iterateJSON(Object object, String key2) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = ((JSONObject) object);
    Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    String key;
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        key = (String) keys.next();
        if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(key);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                iterateJSON(array.get(i), key);
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
            iterateJSON(jsonObject.get(key), key2 + "." + key);
        } else {
            if (!colNames.contains(key2 + "." + key))
                colNames.add(key2 + "." + key);
            continue;
        }
    }
}

static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String(encoded, encoding);
}

}
```

Sample Input Json I have taken:

```
{  
   "id":"1",
    "name":{  
      "first_name":"Joe",
      "last_name":"Thomas"
   },
   "address":[  
      {  
         "first_line":"Joe",
         "city":{  
            "city_name":"Bangalore",
            "city_pin":650659
         }
      },
      {  
         "first_line":"Joe",
         "city":{  
            "city_name":"Bangalore",
            "city_pin":650659,
            "city_pin2":65065933
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Output:

```
address.first_line
address.city.city_name
address.city.city_pin
address.city.city_pin2
name.last_name
name.first_name
id
```