# Changing nested column names using SparklyR in R

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have referred to all the links mentioned here:

1) [Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622262/sparklyr-change-all-column-names-spark-dataframe) 2) [Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514906/sparklyr-change-columns-names-in-a-spark-dataframe) 3) [Link-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601609/fetching-all-column-names-in-nested-json) 4) [Link-4](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/900)

Following R code has been written by using Sparklyr Package. It reads huge JSON file and creates database schema.

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = conf, version = '2.2.0') # Connection
sample_tbl <- spark_read_json(sc,name="example",path="example.json", header = TRUE, 
                              memory = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE) # reads JSON file
sample_tbl <- sdf_schema_viewer(sample_tbl) # to create db schema
df <- tbl(sc,"example") # to create lookup table
```

It has created following database schema

[image: Database Schema]

Now,

If I rename first level column, then it works.

For example,

```
df %>% rename(ent = entities)
```

But when I run 2nd deep level nested column then it doesn't rename.

```
df %>% rename(e_hashtags = entities.hashtags)
```

It shows error:

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'entities.hashtags' not found
```

**Question**

My question is, how to rename 3rd to 4th deep level nested column also?

Please refer database schema mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Spark as such doesn't support renaming individual nested fields. You have to either cast or rebuild a whole structure. For simplicity let's assume that data looks as follows:

```
cat('{"contributors": "foo", "coordinates": "bar", "entities": {"hashtags": ["foo", "bar"], "media": "missing"}}',  file = "/tmp/example.json")
df <- spark_read_json(sc, "df", "/tmp/example.json", overwrite=TRUE)

df %>% spark_dataframe() %>% invoke("schema") %>% invoke("treeString") %>% cat()
```

```
root
 |-- contributors: string (nullable = true)
 |-- coordinates: string (nullable = true)
 |-- entities: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hashtags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- media: string (nullable = true)
```

with simple string representation:

```
df %>% 
  spark_dataframe() %>% 
  invoke("schema") %>% 
  invoke("simpleString") %>% 
  cat(sep = "\n")
```

```
struct<contributors:string,coordinates:string,entities:struct<hashtags:array<string>,media:string>>
```

With cast you have to define expression using matching type description:

```
expr_cast <- invoke_static(
  sc, "org.apache.spark.sql.functions", "expr",
  "CAST(entities AS struct<e_hashtags:array<string>,media:string>)"
)

df_cast <- df %>% 
  spark_dataframe() %>% 
  invoke("withColumn", "entities", expr_cast) %>% 
  sdf_register()

df_cast %>% spark_dataframe() %>% invoke("schema") %>% invoke("treeString") %>% cat()
```

```
root
 |-- contributors: string (nullable = true)
 |-- coordinates: string (nullable = true)
 |-- entities: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- e_hashtags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- media: string (nullable = true)
```

To rebuild structure you have to match all components:

```
expr_struct <- invoke_static(
  sc, "org.apache.spark.sql.functions", "expr",
  "struct(entities.hashtags AS e_hashtags, entities.media)"
)

df_struct <- df %>% 
  spark_dataframe() %>% 
  invoke("withColumn", "entities", expr_struct) %>% 
  sdf_register()

df_struct %>% spark_dataframe() %>% invoke("schema") %>% invoke("treeString") %>% cat()
```

```
root
 |-- contributors: string (nullable = true)
 |-- coordinates: string (nullable = true)
 |-- entities: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- e_hashtags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- media: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: This doesn't affect this answer in any practical way. Column is always identified but its fully qualified name. The ambiguity occurs only in rare cases where you have columns of the same named, at the same path (let's say you'd have `entities.url` and `entities.url` - this are border cases though, and typically indicate mistakes in pipeline or serious data problems).

Comment: You have to recreate a whole structure. If you have multiple levels of nesting, you need multiple nested structs reflecting that `struct(..., struct(...))` and so on. However not all structures can be build like this.